# Beginner level - saving str to an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Hey guys I really need your help.

I tried for a while to understand how arrays work and using a for loop to search inside of them and that seems to be working.

My first question is, how can I add something to my array inside the while loop in this program?

The functionality is as follows: 
add A string to the array, 
print out the whole array, 
search inside of the array

Any help is appreciated.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool isRunning = true;
        int menyVal;
        int Allitem = 5;
        string[] rygga = new string[Allitem];
        rygga[0] = "1";
        rygga[1] = "2";
        rygga[2] = "3";
        rygga[3] = "";
        rygga[4] = "";


        while (isRunning)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\tVälkommen till ryggsäcken! vänligen välj ett av dessa val med en siffra.");

            Console.WriteLine("\t[1]Lägg till föremål / add item");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[2]Skriv ut innehållet/ print out all");
            Console.WriteLine("\t[3]Sök i ryggsäcken/ search in the array");
            Console.Write("\tVälj en siffra: / choose a number ");
            int menyval = Convert.ToInt32(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menyVal));

            //Använda menyvalet med switch

            switch (menyVal)
            {

                case 1:
                    {

                        //Spara användarens föremål
                        Console.Write("skriv vad föremålet heter för att spara det i ryggsäcken: ");

                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        //visa vad som ligger sparat i ryggsäcken





                        break;
                    }

               case 3:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Skriv in ett sökord : ");


                        string sökOrd = Console.ReadLine();
                        try
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < rygga.Length; i++)
                            {
                                if (rygga[i] == sökOrd)
                                    Console.WriteLine(rygga[i]);
                            }

                            Console.ReadLine();

                        }
                        catch
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("Inget hittades! ");

                        }
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {

                        // med uppmaningen att skriva 0 - 4

                        Console.WriteLine("Du måste välja en siffra mellan 0-4!");



                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"how can I add something to my array inside the while"_ well, what have you tried? Why you need a while-loop at all and not a for-loop(because the size of the array is known)? You can assign a string to the `string[]` via index: `rygga[0] = "foo";`. But you have already done this, so the question is pretty unclear.

Comment: arrays are really a fixed size thing - so,  you have 5 with [3] and [4] empty, youve shown you know how to assign things to the array so you can do just that if you now need a 6 big array, a list would be a better call

Comment: I will go ahead and give you a really good advice. Do not formulate your code in your native language. In this case Swedish. Use English instead. For your own and others sake. It makes it more semantic and friendly.

Comment: You can´t *add* something to your array, as an array has a fix size. You can however change the elenet at a given position within an array or even replace that item. If you really want to *add* or *remove* an element, you´re better be off by using a `List<string>`. It also gives you index-based access (e.g. `rygga[0]`) but enables dynamic re-sizing of the internal datastructure.

Comment: Sorry if I'm confusing I'm really trying my best to be as coherent as possible.  I want the user to have the possibility to save something inside the array, and with the first case in this which statement I have no clue what I should use in order to save a  string to the array.

 I also want to know how to print out all of the things that is currently saved  in the array

Comment: i get it thanks for all your input.

Answer (score 1):

Your Array can only contain 5 (Allitem) entries. You could search for the next empty entry in the array with:

```
int emptyindex = -1;
foreach(string s in rygga)
{
  if(s == "")
  {
    emptyIndex = Array.IndexOf(rygga,s);
    break;
  }
}

if(emptyindex >= 0)
{
  rygga[emptyindex] = //UserInput;
}
else
{
 //Inform that there is no more space to fill
 //Eventually you can overwrite index 0 then. Depends on what suits you better
}
```

If you really need to **add** an unknown amount of times, an array is not the way to go. Better to use

```
List<string> rygga = new List<string>();
rygga.Add(//UserInput);
```

For that you have to import

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

**EDIT:**

In both cases (List and Array) you can simply go:

```
foreach(string s in rygga)
{
  Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```